# Unable to get only 1 occurrence of links

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have 3 unique links inside anchor tag in HTML. All links occur 2 times. What i am trying to do is fetch 3 links only once using python regex match but unable to do so and that's it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul class="asidemenu_h1">
            <li class="top">
            <h3>Mobiles</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-apple/" title="Apple Mobiles Price">Apple</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-asus/" title="Asus Mobiles Price">Asus</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-black_berry/" title="Black Berry Mobiles Price">Black Berry</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="start2" id="start2ul63" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
            <li>
            <h3>Mobiles</h3>
                <ul class="start3 bolder-star">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-apple/">Apple</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-asus/">Asus</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.mega.pk/mobiles-black_berry/">Black Berry</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my approach(1) using for loop with regex match:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r'(http:\/\/www\.mega\.pk\/mobiles-[A-z]+\/)(?=.*\1)', re.DOTALL)):
    link.get('href')
```

This returns nothing at all.

Here is my approach(2) using for loop with regex match:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r'(http:\/\/www\.mega\.pk\/mobiles-\w+\/)(?!.*\1)', re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL)):
    link.get('href')
```

This returns repeated links as well.

Comment: I already know regex, so far i find beautifulsoup difficult to use.

Comment: You could return a set of links found; that'll automatically deduplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all links having `mobiles` inside `href` with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("ul.asidemenu_h1 a[href*=mobiles]")
```

Note that I'm restricting it to search for the links inside the `ul` having `asidemenu_h1` class - this alone would help you to avoid duplicates. `*=` here means "contains".

---

If you insist on using regular expressions to check the `href` values:

```
menu = soup.find("ul", class_="asidemenu_h1")
links = menu.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"mega\.pk\/mobiles-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/$"))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_text())
```

Comment: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token).
I am using python 3.5.

Comment: @MansoorAkram ah, yeah, sure, forgot about it's limitations in bs4, updated. Check it out.

Comment: @MansoorAkram just a minor warning - watch out that trailing slash at the end of the url (it could be optional and you might get links with and without it). Glad to help.